# Excel VBA: Extract substrings from multiple comma separated strings using formulas or macro in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have the following list on Sheet1:

```
    COLUMN A    COLUMN B
 1  ADDRESS     VEHICLE(S) USED
 2  Address1    Vehicle1, Vehicle3, Vehicle4
 3  Address2    Vehicle1, Vehicle3, Vehicle4
 4  Address3    Vehicle1, Vehicle2, Vehicle5
 5  Address4    Vehicle1, Vehicle6 
 6  Address1    Vehicle2, Vehicle4, Vehicle6 
 7  Address2    Vehicle2, Vehicle3
 8  Address1    Vehicle2, Vehicle5
```

On Sheet2, I would like the following output in Column D when I enter "Address1" in cell B1

```
   COLUMN A    COLUMN B    COLUMN C         COLUMN D
1  ADDRESS     Address 1   VEHICLE(S) USED  Vehicle1
2                                           Vehicle2
3                                           Vehicle3
4                                           Vehicle4
5                                           Vehicle5
6                                           Vehicle6
```

Is there a way to perform this using a visual basic macro ?

Comment: You can use a `Dictionary`

Comment: I have provided a way of doing this manually  -  You have asked for how to do this using VBA  -  What have you tried so far? rather than just asking for code you should show at least try yourself and if you then provide the code you have tried I (and others) would be more likely to help you resolve any issues you have.

Comment: @Phil S. see my answer (long and detailed) below , and let me know if it works for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phil, you can use Dictionary object as it was mentioned in comment, here is small example below (but withnout sorting venicles, i think it would be easy for you).

So my input is:

[image: Input]

Solution based on dictionary:

```
Public Sub ExractSubstringsFromBlaBlaBla(ByVal GiveMeAddress As String)
    Dim GatheredStrings As Object
    Dim Addresses As Variant
    Dim VeniclesUsed As Variant
    Dim SubResult() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    'Setting up info
    Set GatheredStrings = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Addresses = Sheets(1).[A2:A8].Value2
    VeniclesUsed = Sheets(1).[B2:B8].Value2

    'Gathering dict
    For i = LBound(Addresses) To UBound(Addresses)
        If GiveMeAddress = Addresses(i, 1) Then
            SubResult = Split(Expression:=VeniclesUsed(i, 1), Delimiter:=", ")
            For j = LBound(SubResult) To UBound(SubResult)
                If Not GatheredStrings.Exists(SubResult(j)) Then _
                        Call GatheredStrings.Add(Key:=SubResult(j), Item:=SubResult(j))
            Next
        End If
    Next

    'If dictionary is empty - lets quit
    If GatheredStrings.Count = 0 Then _
            Exit Sub

    Sheets(2).[A1].Value2 = GiveMeAddress
    'Resize and transpose array to fit in vertical direction
    Sheets(2).[B1].Resize(GatheredStrings.Count).Value2 = _
            Application.Transpose(GatheredStrings.Keys)
End Sub
```

My output is (withnout sorting venicles):

[image: output]

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you CommonSense! I must admit that I am very new to using VBA.  Can you explain how to run this script?  I went to the Developer tab, and selected Visual Basic. Then I selected Insert>Module.  I copy/paste the code and ran it.  At that point the Macros box appears and asks to provide a name. Once I enter the name, it only gives me the option to create which takes ma back to the VBA editor.

Comment: Also, I wanted to clarify one thing.  This example showed 4 Addresses and 6 Vehicles.  In reality, there are only 6 Vehicles available, but the number of different Addresses will only increase over time.  I am pulling this output from a Google Forms response form, which will be updated approximately 4 times per week.  Each time it is updated it adds the responses to only one row with many columns (approx 70). This explains why the vehicles are returned in one cell separated by commas.

Comment: The reason why Address1 had 3 lines, is because they were submitted on 3 different days.  The point of this is to track which vehicles were used at an address over time.

Comment: @Phil S. Hello again, this code is just example, you can't run it directly because you need to pass argument `GiveMeAddress`. You can move declaration of `GiveMeAddress` into sub declaration and grab name from inputbox like this `GiveMeAddress = InputBox("Give me some input")`. Numbers of your addresses doesnt matter except of lines where you setting up 'Addresses' and `VeniclesUsed` - you need to replace this two lines 'Sheets(1).[**:**]' with some actual ranges. Try to google how to find used range of your sheets!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'text to columns' feature & also the 'transpose' copy and paste function do this task.

In Excel 2010 this can be found on the ribbon under the Data tab

You select the column you want to split, in this case that would be 'Column B' and then click on the 'text to columns' button in the ribbon.

This opens up a wizard to guide you through the process, 
On the first screen you would select 'delimited' as you have stated you have comma separated strings, On the second screen select Comma under the Delimiters heading.
The third screen allows you to select the column data format (General, Text, Date)

Once you click finish it will separate out the selected column.
You can copy the results and then paste them into a new area using 'paste special' and transpose  -  This will swap the data from multiple columns to multiple rows.

Comment: did you read the last line in the post ? he asks "Is there a way to perform this using a visual basic macro ? "

Comment: Yes I did - I am giving a way of doing this manually as the question title mentions formula......

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a bit long, but the code is quite simple with detailed steps.

**Process/Code steps**:

1. The code is placed in "Sheet2" module in the `Worksheet_Change` event, and checks if a value in Column B is modified (can extend to a single cell of "B1" if needed), if it does it calls the `FilterAddress` Sub, and sends the `Target.Value`.
2. Use `AutoFilter` in "Sheet1" according to the value entered in Cell B1 in "Sheet2".
3. Loop through Visible cells, with `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` , and by using the `Dictionary` object, keep only unique "Vehicles".
4. Store the unique "Vehicles" in the Dictionary to `VehicleArr` array.
5. Sort the `VehicleArr` array by their string values (smallest to largest).
6. Paste the values according to PO request to "Sheet2".

---

**Worksheet_Change Code** ("Sheet2" module)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' call Function only if modifed cell is in Column "B"
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Call FilterAddress(Target.Value)
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

---

**Sub FilterAddress Code** (Regular module)

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterAddress(FilterVal As String)

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FilterRng As Range, cell As Range
Dim Dict As Object
'Dim ID
Dim Vehicle     As Variant
Dim VehicleArr  As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long


With Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' find last row with data in column "A" (Adress)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set FilterRng = .Range("A1:B" & LastRow)

    .Range("A1").AutoFilter
    ' AutoFilter "Sheet1" according to value in "Sheet2" in Column B
    FilterRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=FilterVal

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' create an array with size up to number of rows >> will resize it later
    ReDim VehicleArr(1 To LastRow)
    j = 1 ' init array counter

    For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        ' read values from cell to array using the Split function
        Vehicle = Split(cell.Value, ",")

        For i = LBound(Vehicle) To UBound(Vehicle)
            Vehicle(i) = Trim(Vehicle(i)) ' remove extra spaces from string

            If Not Dict.exists(Vehicle(i)) Then
                Dict.Add Vehicle(i), Vehicle(i)

                ' save Vehicle Name to array >> will use it later for "Bubble-sort" and paste in "Sheet2"
                VehicleArr(j) = Vehicle(i)
                j = j + 1 ' increment VehicleArr counter
            End If
        Next i

    Next cell
    ' resize array up to number of actual Vehicle
    ReDim Preserve VehicleArr(1 To j - 1)

End With

Dim VehicleTmp As Variant
' Bubble-sort Vehicle Array >> sorts the Vehicle array from smallest to largest
For i = 1 To UBound(VehicleArr) - 1
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(VehicleArr)
        If VehicleArr(j) < VehicleArr(i) Then
            VehicleTmp = VehicleArr(j)
            VehicleArr(j) = VehicleArr(i)
            VehicleArr(i) = VehicleTmp
        End If
    Next j
Next i

' now the "fun" part >> paste to "Sheet2"
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("A1").Value = "ADDRESS"
    .Range("B1").Value = FilterVal
    .Range("C1").Value = "VEHICLE(S) USED"

    ' clear contents from previous run
    .Range("D1:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
    .Range("D1:D" & UBound(VehicleArr)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VehicleArr)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Shai Rado.  For some reason, I am unable to get this code to run. I opened a blank workbook, copied my data from my original post,  then opened visual basic, then copied the above code in the appropriate locations.  When I try to run the code, the Macro box pops and ask to enter the name.  It does not give me the option to select the ones i pasted (FilterAddress).

Comment: @PhilS. you don't need to paste it. Once you copied the code in `Worksheet_Change` to your "Sheet2" , and the other one to a regular separate module. Save the Excel file as `.xlsm`. Then, once you finish typing in Cell B1 in "Sheet2" the value of "Address1" (or other valid options), the code suppose to run.

Comment: Thank you.  I was able to get the correct result after I typed in "Address1" on Sheet2.  Can you tell me if there is a way to reset the worksheet if I delete the value in B1 and add another value?  The only way I can do that is to not save the file, close it, and then reopen it if I want to see the results of another address (Address2)

Comment: @PhilS.  You can change the value in cell B1 in sheet 2, and every time you do you will get new results on-the-fly. That's not the way you want it ?

Comment: That is what I was hoping would happen. However when I would change B1  to another address, the sheet would not update. I noticed after i deleted or changed B1 on Sheet2, the filter was still in place on Sheet1.  I added  'FilterRng.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False'  at the end of the code.  This clears the filter after the lines are copied on Sheet2, and allowed me to change values on B1 without issue.

Comment: If I wanted to move the contents (Address) of B1 to B4, and the contents of D1:D6 (Vehicles) to start on B50, how would I edit the code?   I tried editing the references in the part that you paste to Sheet2, but I kept encountering problems. Since there will potentially be other data between B4 and B50, I want to make sure the `clearcontents` does not delete anything between those two cells.

Comment: I changed the line`.Range("D1:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents` to `.Range("B55:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents` and the line '.Range("D1:D" & UBound(VehicleArr)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VehicleArr)` to `.Range("B50:B55" & UBound(VehicleArr)) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VehicleArr)`  but it is giving me "#N/A" in cells B56 through B556.

Comment: @PhilS.  But this is already not related to your post, now you want to add logics to the paste section. You should open a new post, add your modified working code, and describe what you are trying to achieve, it will allow other users on So to help you (and me). In the meantime, if my answer here helped you solve your problem, please mark as "Answer".

Comment: @PhilS. please mark as "Answer" (by clicking the little **V** next to my post)

Comment: @PhilS.  You took "off" my answer ? Why ?